# Data inconsistent when using group by and min clauses with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, inner-join

I am trying to fetch upcoming event based on start time from a table.
let us assume the following :
Actually we are joining to tables. In table A Locationid is primary key. We are joining another table to fetch name of the venue. 
You may think that we have redundant data but they are not. A user is visiting same venue on different days.

[image]

Now i would like to display only the upcoming plan i.e

**locationid 2511 and 2515**

Here is the query i am trying

```
 SELECT B.`VenueID` ,
 A.rather_to_be_flying_now,
 A.my_favorite,
 A.Locationid,
 MIN( A.start ) ,
 MIN( A.end ) 
    FROM tbl_userselectedlocations A
    INNER JOIN tbl_Flyingapp_Venue B ON A.VenueID = B.VenueID
    WHERE A.Pilotid =  '709'
    GROUP BY  `VenueID` 
    ORDER BY A.my_favorite DESC , A.start
```

But at this point i am getting incorrect data 
It should be

Locationid= **2511 and 2515 in the order respectively and not 2514 and 2516**
[image]

Is anything wrong in the query?

Had try with inner queries. NOT using **INNER JOIN** here but the resultant values are different.

```
SELECT  A.Locationid, MIN(A.start), MIN(A.end)
FROM tbl_userselectedlocations A

WHERE A.Pilotid =  '709'
group by VenueID
ORDER BY A.my_favorite DESC , A.start
```

Comment: yes, once you group, you no longer have separate records, instead you have a group of records, and just because you select the min(A.start) your query doesn't know to select the Locationid associated with that record.

Comment: You are grouping by `venueID` only, and you used aggregate functions with `start` and `end`. But what about `rather_to_be_flying_now`, `my_favorite` and `Locationinid`? what do you want to select for these columns for each group of `valueID`? Any columns that are not included in the group by clause, must be used with an aggregated function. If you include them without an aggregate functions, mysql picks up an arbitrary value for them. Thats why you were getting inconsistent data for those three columns.

Comment: could you please run your query again but with "ORDER BY `VenueID` ?

Comment: @Guido I tried as you said but it is still returning incorrect records

Comment: @MahmoudGamal i cannot aggregate remaining attributes because those values are not mandatory and so are sometimes empty. locationid is a primary key so it is always distinct from others

Comment: Just curious, why are you even joining table `B`? You are only pulling in `VenueID` which is duplicated in table `A`, correct?

Comment: @Asok the details such as venuename, address etc are from table B

Comment: @pburgess Is there any solution?

Comment: You get those results because you are using `group by` incorrectly. MySQL simply chooses random values in that case (other DBMS would reject your query for precisely that reason). See this for details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding just the desired start time for each venue using a subquery,
then finding the rest of the information from that row by a self join
using the values of venueID and start:

```
SELECT B.VenueID, A.rather_bo_be_flying_now, A.my_favorite,
       A.Locationid, A.start, A.end
FROM (SELECT venueID, MIN(start) AS start 
      FROM tbl_userselectedlocations
      GROUP BY venueID) AS Z
INNER JOIN tbl_userselectedlocations A
ON A.VenueID = Z.VenueID AND A.start = Z.start
INNER JOIN tbl_Flyingapp_Venue B 
ON A.VenueID = B.VenueID
WHERE A.Pilotid = '709'
ORDER BY A.My_favorite DESC, A.start
```

Comment: Yeah i tried and partially succeeded. But when i query with MIN(start), the start time may be 0000-00-00 00:00:00. so if the start time is 0 i would like to display next upcoming date.
i:e if i have two plans for Washington with start time as 0000-00-00 and 2013-02-01 i just want to retrieve location with start date 2013-02-01

Comment: Then add `WHERE start > '0000-00-00'` (or today's date to find only future events) to the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

You probably first need a sub-select:

```
SELECT  C.VenueID            ,
    A.rather_to_be_flying_now,
    A.my_favorite            ,
    A.Locationid             ,
    C.STARTP                 ,
    C.ENDP
FROM    
(
    SELECT   D.VenueID                ,
             MIN( D.start ) AS STARTP ,
             MIN( D.end )   AS ENDP
    FROM     tbl_userselectedlocations D
    WHERE     D.Pilotid = '709'
    GROUP BY `VenueID`
) C
INNER JOIN tbl_userselectedlocations A
ON      A.VenueID = C.VenueID
INNER JOIN tbl_Flyingapp_Venue B
ON      A.VenueID = B.VenueID
ORDER BY A.my_favorite DESC ,
         C.STARTP
```

Comment: Sorry order by venueid id doesn't solve, Also i need result order by start time. i:e Chronologically

Comment: Thank you, But It is returning empty set. Unable to figure out where it is going wrong

Comment: could you try again but without: INNER JOIN tbl_Flyingapp_Venue B
ON      A.VenueID = B.VenueID

Comment: No. I really appreciate your effort. Many thanks. It's somewhat close. Probably the main issue might be the improper usage of group by !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query i used,

```
 $query="select distinct(`VenueID`),MIN(start) from  tbl_userselectedlocations 
 where `Pilotid` = '709' group by `VenueID`  order by `my_favorite` DESC ,start";
```

while loop here and

```
   select * from tbl_userselectedlocations
   where VenueID = '$row[0]' and start='$row[1]' and Pilotid='709'";
```

This gives the result, But if i have the following records
[image]

```
MIN(start)
```

will return only **locationid with 2511 but i need to show 2514 as an upcoming plan**
Any idea